# Angular-material flex tile design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I try to use angular material for creating tiled design of my app. At one of my pages I have some elements, which are displayed by ng-repeat and custom directive:

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in hc.elements" flex-gt-md="30" flex-gt-sm="40" flex-gt-xs="80" flex-xs="80">
```

When where are more than 3 elements it looks ok, but when the number of elements is 2, than appears a trouble with displaying - each element has a smaller width when in case with 3 elements. Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found at parent container which had `layout-align="center center"`. Fixed with adding `flex="100"` to another middle parent (child of main parent but parent for my elements).